# SSL Certificate WPEngine to Heroku Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https

We had a website on WPEngine with SSL activated, so every pages were served over https.

We recently switch to Ruby on Rails on Heroku. And now we have some errors showing up when we use https :

```
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from myapp.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

When I do a `curl` check both for my custom domain or the herokuapp domain, the SSL is verified.

```
curl -kvI https://myapp.herokuapp.com
# SSL certificate verify ok.
curl -kvI https://myapp.com
# SSL certificate verify ok.
```

The error in Chrome is:

```
This server could not prove that it is myapp.com; its security certificate is from *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

In my production.rb I have :

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with our Java app a while ago. I may be wrong, but Heroku PaaS has their cloud proxy behind dynos, which does overwrite request headers by default (in our case from https-to-http). I think you may be interested in checking [`X-Forwarded-For`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#client-ip-address) header.  Our solution was in explicit passing request context parameters in `Procfile`.

Procfile should contain something like (for Java):
`..--context-xml <contextWithHeaderOptions>..`

Actual `context.xml`:

```
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" portHeader="x-forwarded-port"/>
</Context>
```